# ¿existe alguna función ya definida en Postgres que te permita saber que acción activa un trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql, funciones, trigger

Quiero hacer un trigger en postgres que va a alimentar un log. Mi trigger se disparará cuando se haga una actualización, inserción o eliminación.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_usuario
    BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE 
    ON public.usuario
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.actualizarlog();
```

Como mi trigger se dispara con cualquiera de las tres acciones, no puedo saber específicamente que acción disparo el trigger, pero en mi log también quiero guardar que acción se realizo. ¿existe alguna función ya definida en postgres que me permita saber que acción específicamente disparo el trigger?

Comment: Prueba con TG_OP https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-trigger.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la variable especial de triggers `TG_OP` dentro de la función trigger

```
CREATE FUNCTION actualizarlog() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
 IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Se realizó una inserción ...';
 END IF;
 IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Se realizó una actualización ...';
 END IF;
 IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Se realizó una eliminación ...';
 END IF;
RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: gracias, si me fue util